# TinkerPop Gremlin Repeat until nodes with specified label

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

In my graph there are 2 type of labels: `a` and `b` and a `boolean` property `travel_by`.

I would like to perform BFS (with max depth of 5): start from a given node and get all the first nodes with label `a`.

I tried to do something like this:

```
g.V(<node_to_start_from>).repeat(__.both().has("travel_by", True).simplePath())
.times(5)
.until(__.hasLabel('a')).toList()
```

But this query is stuck for a really long time (even if I change to `times(2)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to do this is to use `loops`

```
g.V(<node_to_start_from>).
  repeat(__.both().has("travel_by", True).simplePath()).
  until(__.hasLabel('a').or().loops().is(5)).
  hasLabel('a').
  toList()
```

The second `has` prevents anything other than items with a label of 'a' from being part of the result in cases where `loops` has reached 5.

Comment: but I do not want to limit the results. I would like to limit the depth using times(), but this does not seems to work

Comment: I'm not quite following - the query I gave you will limit the depth to a maximum of 5. Did you try my query suggestion? If you can update the question with some sample data and expected output I will be happy to update the answer. Or is it that you only want results at depth 5?

Comment: ohhh, I did not realize loops limits the depth :). Anyway I tried your query but I get "invalid syntax" around the first or statement

Comment: Can you please share the error message you are getting? The query works fine for me. How are you submitting the query? If you are using Gremlin Python you may need to replace `or()` with `or_()`

Comment: Amazing! you were right: I missed or_() and is_(). Working perfectly, tx!